# UITextField crashes app if keyboard is set to specific language with continue as return key

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, keyboard, uitextfield

If you set your preferred language to Albanian(Shqip) and your keyboard to Albanian language your app will crash if you tap on an UITextField that has it's return type set to Continue.

[Phone Language Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JiFe.png)

[UITextField options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRKo1.jpg)

The error that Xcode throws:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]`

Answer (score 0):

It may be an Apple bug. From exception, it looks like it is crashing because of an empty placeholder value. Try adding some text value to Placeholder Text.

Comment: I tried adding Placeholder but the end result is the same. Where should I report this bug?

Comment: you can report the issue here:
https://feedbackassistant.apple.com